# How to create an array of non-retained objects in arc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

How to create an array of non-retained objects in arc? These objects are observers in this  array. Currently, I'm creating this array in this way:

```
_observers = CFBridgingRelease(CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL));
```

The problem is the code crashes sometimes when making notifications in this line:

```
for (NSInteger i = [_observers count] - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

  // crash line
  id<ListModelObserver> observer = (id<ListModelObserver>)[_observers objectAtIndex:i];
  ...
```

I have zombies enabled on, and clearly see observer object classname in debug console. The observer object should be already removed from _observers during dealloc... The only thing that comes to my mind is _observers array somehow retains its objects. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're releasing the array, not the objects. If you want to have a collection of unsafe unrestrained pointers to objects, then either use a C array or set up a CFArrayRef that doesn't include any call back functions.

Comment: This. Perhaps to clarify: NSArray, by definition, retains objects added to it.

Comment: @Graham I assume "CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL)" third NULL parameter already does not include any callback functions...